# Are random selections from i.i.d. random variables independent?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let us have **identically independently distributed** random variables $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{10}$. Now let us pick indices $\alpha, \beta$ **uniformly independently** from $1,2,\dots,10$. Are variables $x_{\alpha}$ and $x_{\beta}$ independent?

My intuition says that **they are not**, since there is a chance $\frac{1}{10}$ that they are the same. But how can I formally prove this? (or prove that they are independent in case I am wrong)

Comment: Can we assume $\alpha,\beta$ independent from x's?

Comment: @ved yes, independent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize:

> With replacement (the question), $(\alpha,\beta)$ is independent and $(x_\alpha,x_\beta)$ is not. Without replacement, $(\alpha,\beta)$ is not independent and $(x_\alpha,x_\beta)$ is.

To show the case with replacement, consider
$$P(x_\alpha\in A,x_\beta\in A)=P(x_\alpha\in A,x_\beta\in A,\alpha\ne\beta)+P(x_\alpha\in A,\alpha=\beta),
$$
thus,
$$
P(x_\alpha\in A,x_\beta\in A)=\left(1-\frac1{10}\right)p^2+\frac1{10}p,
$$
where $p=P(x_1\in A)$. On the other hand,
$$
P(x_\alpha\in A)P(x_\beta\in A)=p^2.
$$
If $p$ is not $0$ or $1$ these are different.

Answer (score 2):

Independence has nothing to do with whether the answers are the same. They can still be independent if answers are the same. Independence has more to do with conditional probability. Two random variables are independent if knowing about outcome of one rv tells you no information about the other rv (i.e. $P(X_\alpha \mid X_\beta=x)=P(X_\alpha)$. Now one way this situation could not be independent is if your numbers from uniform $1,2,\ldots,10$ where selected without replacement.

Comment: Also to prove independence just use definition which is outcome A and B are independent if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$

Comment: "Without replacements" means that the $x_i$s are _not_ independent, contrary to the assumption in the question.

Comment: yea I was just trying to give an an example of situation that would be considered not independent

Comment: x @user159813: But your example is not an example of the situation in the question. As Did's computation shows, $x_\alpha$ and $x_\beta$ are actually not independent with any nontrivial probability distribution for the $x_i$s.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I must have miss interpreted the question or not thought it through enough thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Without replacement, $X_\alpha$ and $X_\beta$ **ARE** independent.

Comment: @HenningMakholm oh made stupid mistake. Read it through too quick, didn't notice it was indices being chosen form random uniform 1,..,10 thought it was variables themselves. Sorry about that

Comment: Then yes I completely agree with you and Did

Comment: And I seem to have misread the answer -- I didn't notice the "not" in the last sentence.

Comment: Yea but as Did pointed out if indices are chosen without replacement would actual mean independence between $X_{\beta}$ and $X_{\alpha}$ so that statement is wrong also still (since you will never get two of same variable thus two different once which are assumed to be independent already)

Comment: @Did by "Without replacement" do you mean $\alpha \neq \beta$?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Of course (what else?). The current last sentence of the post is ambiguous: without replacement, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not independent but this is not the point, rather one asks whether $x_\alpha$ and $x_\beta$ are independent (and they are).